# How to list the changed file names in the latest build comparing with old in GIT?

Tags: git, github, devops-services

What i am trying to achieve?
I want to list out the filename in the projectbuild2 branch commit changes.

If possible by commit user wise.

I have tried with the log it is showing only the folder itself not the entire build.

Could anyone help me on this.

Thanks,
Dinesh.

Comment: Do you mean you ant to compare the whole project at an older of itself ? if so you will need either to clone its version to a temporary place & script compare or to use an external tool ; as far as I know

Comment: Are you looking for `git log --name-status` ? or `--name-only` ?